Fish: To match only files or only folders
In Zsh, to match only files or only folders, I can use *(^/) and *(/) (or *(^/D) and *(/D), if I need to exclude hidden ones).
Is it possible to match only files or only folders in Fish?

Hm, again, this is straight up answered by reading the official fish documentation exactly as it's written. file:///usr/share/doc/fish/language.html#expand-wildcard , and even links to the modules with which you can filter results instead.

@MarcusMüller I couldn't an example for matching only files there, i.e. excluding directories. */ works for matching only directories, though.

@MarcusMüller Could you provide a good practical example? I tried, for instance, ls */, and this somewhat works: it shows me top-level folders without top-level files. But it also shows me the contents of those folders. How to show the top-level folders themselves only, without their contents?

not a fish trick, but simply the -d flag for ls.
